# BAT File will not start another BAT file after ant command

Tags: xml, shell, ant, vbscript, command-prompt

I have a .bat file that runs an ANT command like

**ant "clean" "debug" "compress" "buildnumber" -f C:\Users\cm\WebstormProjects\GAME\build\build.xml**

After this ant command I have this

**start run_vbs.bat**

and this command is not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to start the ant batch file:

```
call ant_batch.bat
```

It's likely that you aren't using the `call` keyword and so the batch file doesn't return control, it just ends.

Comment: the ant_batch.bat is called from within File Watchers. This is a plugin I use with Webstorm because the newest version of Webstorm does not support ant.
So File Watchers calls ant_batch.bat every time I save my .js Files

Comment: Put `start run_vbs.bat` at the end of the ant batch file.

Comment: I allready have this command in my ant batch file. this is actually my problem that the ant batch file does not run another batch file, in my case run_vbs.bat

Comment: Put `pause` after the run-vbs.bat and you will probably see an error message but replace the `start` with `call` also.

Comment: i can only see outputs from ant like all task that were executed or BUILD SUCCESSFUL but no sign that run_vbs.bat was executed

Comment: thank you for all the advices you gave me. they were all right but the problem was that I was not calling ant command correctly

Answer (score 1):

I had to call ant from my ant_batch.bat like this

**call ant "clean" "debug" "compress" "buildnumber" -f C:\Users\cm\WebstormProjects\GAME\build\build.xml**

So it is necessary to use the keyword "call" while calling ant because the other commands that are after the ant-call will not be executed.

Comment: That's precisely the advice I gave you - to use `call` in a batch file because it will not return control if you don't use `call`.  `Ant` is a batch file too, right?

Comment: ohh sorry, I misunderstood you. I will give you the right answer then